# Copy selected lines from one file and insert those lines in another file after selected line

Tags: perl

Here is my question let's say I have a file
`file1.txt` with contents:

```
abc.. 
def.. 
ghi.. 
def..
```

and second file `file2.txt` with contents:

```
xxx..
yyy..
zzz..
```

Now I want to copy all the line starting with "def" in `file1.txt` to `file2.txt` and append after "yyy..." line in `file2.txt`

#### Expected Output:

```
xxx...
yyy...
def...
def...
zzz...
```

I am pretty much new to perl, I've tried writing simple code for this but end up with output only appending at the end of file

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w 
use strict; 
use warnings;
use vars qw($filecontent $total);
my $file1 = "file1.txt";
open(FILE1, $file1) || die "couldn't open the file!";
open(FILE2, '>>file2.txt') || die "couldn't open the file!";
  while($filecontent = <FILE1>){
    if ( $filecontent =~ /def/ ) {
      chomp($filecontent);
       print FILE2 $filecontent ."\n";
      #print FILE2 $filecontent ."\n" if $filecontent =~/yyy/;
    }  
  } 
 close (FILE1); 
 close (FILE2);
```

output of the perl program is

```
xxx...
yyy...
zzz...
def...
def...
```

Comment: You are using `>>` for opening `file2`. Thus, you will append your output to **the end** of `file2`. Therefore, one way would be: open `file3`. Copy everything from `file2` until `yyy...`. Then use your `while` statement and then copy the rest of `file2` to `file3`.

Comment: The use of `use vars` is discouraged. You should use `my` to declare variables here, and not use global, but declare the variables in the smallest scope possible, preferably right where they are used. E.g. `while (my $filecontent = <FILE1>)`.

Comment: How big are your files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use a temp file.

1. Read and print all lines (to temp) from FILE2 until you hit "yyy"
2. Read and print all "def" lines (to temp) from FILE1
3. Read and print (to temp) the rest of FILE2
4. Rename the temp file to FILE2

```perl
use strict; 
use warnings;

my $file1 = "file1.txt";
my $file2 = "file2.txt";
my $file3 = "file3.txt";

open(FILE1, '<', $file1) or die "couldn't open the file!";
open(FILE2, '<', $file2) or die "couldn't open the file!";
open(FILE3, '>', $file3) or die "couldn't open temp file";

while (<FILE2>) {
  print FILE3;
  if (/^yyy/) {
    last;
  }
}

while (<FILE1>) {
  if (/^def/) {
    print FILE3;
  }
}

while (<FILE2>) {
  print FILE3;
}

close (FILE1); 
close (FILE2);
close (FILE3);

rename($file3, $file2) or die "unable to rename temp file";
```

Comment: Simple and robust +1. You might want to include file name and error in the `die` messages, e.g. `die "couldn't open $file1: $!"`. Using lexical file handles is also recommended, e.g. `my $file1` instead of `FILE1`. Also, `File::Copy::move()` is sometimes recommended over the built-in `rename`.

Comment: All good points - just didn't want to deviate farther from the original code than necessary, to give the OP fewer changes to digest. While `File::Copy::move()` is more flexible, in this simple case we need *exactly* the one thing that `rename()` does, with no additional package imports required.

Comment: I think using correct code is essential, since this is a learning environment. Lead by example, and all that.

Comment: @TLP good catch about $file1 during die message, when I try File::Copy::move() resulted in use of uninitialized value in..perl-5.8.3/lib/5.8.3/File/Copy.pm line 184. That's were moved to a more simple method.

Comment: @vjemmaN You cut out the crucial part of the error message. Line 184 in `File/Copy.pm` is `close($to_h) || goto fail_open2 if $closeto;` and the only thing there that can get the uninitialized warning is `close`, and it is unlikely that it is that.

Comment: @TLP is there a reason to avoid rename() when operating inside same directory?

Comment: @Сухой27 In perldoc -f rename is the information I have.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do this is with the [`Tie::File`](https://metacpan.org/module/Tie::File) module, that lets you access a file as a simple array of strings.

I have also used `first_index` from [`List::MoreUtils`](https://metacpan.org/module/List::MoreUtils) to find where to insert the records.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::File;
use List::MoreUtils qw/ first_index /;

tie my @file1, 'Tie::File', 'file1.txt' or die $!;
tie my @file2, 'Tie::File', 'file2.txt' or die $!;

my $insert = first_index { /^yyy/ } @file2;

for (@file1) {
  if ( /^def/ ) {
    splice @file2, ++$insert, 0, $_;
  }
}
```

**output** (file2.txt)

```
xxx..
yyy..
def.. 
def..
zzz..
```

Your test data doesn't cover it, but the records from `file1.txt` are inserted into `file2.txt` in the order that they appear.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try the [`IO::All`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::All) module:

```
use IO::All;
my ($f1, $f2, $i) = (io('file1.txt'), io('file2.txt'), 1);
for (@$f2) {
    splice(@$f2, $i, 0, grep /^def/, @$f1), last
        if /^yyy/;
    $i++;
}
```